# Plot a bar graph which is both stacked and clustered

Tags: gnuplot, bar-chart

How to draw such a graph with gnuplot.

[image]

Comment: Your question isn't reasonably scoped. Someone could possibly write a book in trying to answer your question. Is there a specific problem you're facing?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing this problem currently, but the accepted answer is not really a suitable solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [demos](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/histograms.html) page for gnuplot shows a similar example of this. (It's the last example on that page, and produces the plot below)

[image: Image from the gnuplot demo page]

Comment: My biggest gripe with that demo page is that it doesn't show you the input data file (i.e., immigration.dat), leaving you to deduce what layout it's in from the other examples. Why not include a link to it on the demos page, gnuplot team?