# Add Custom labels (from a data coloumn series) to bar graph in GNUPlot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a bar graphs representing the energy values of each amino acid in a protein. Here I am sharing the sample data as image below and actual data.

---

See Data and Sample Graph Image I need [here](http://sdrv.ms/19ivx4Z).

---

Now, I want to plot a graph looking something like this using GNUPlot. in which I can have custom labels for each bar from respective Protein*Label series columns.

---

See image [here](http://sdrv.ms/12ZRN00)

---

For preparing this graph I used MS Office with "XY CHART Label" Addin, But It involves too much manual interference, and I have to prepare hundreds of plots like this. So I think GNUPlot (or something else) will be a good option which allow me the automation.

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific. Have you tried anything in GNUplot? If your question is just: Can I generate that plot other than with Excel, say using GNUplot, the answer is: yes, you can. But I don't think that is really your question.

Comment: @Schorsch Yes, Did any one tried this previously, just share some hints, I will pickup from there, like how to call custom labels ??.
I tried a lot by doing google search but no satisfactory results ?? ?? ?

Comment: You can get started [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327576/how-do-you-plot-bar-charts-in-gnuplot), [or here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023736/gnuplot-barchart-histogram-with-errorbars), [maybe here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174846/gnuplot-bar-chart-from-a-function), [or here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235683/how-to-display-a-stacked-barchart-in-gnuplot).

Comment: Additionally, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315195/plot-a-bar-graph-which-is-both-stacked-and-clustered) [or this](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.2/histograms.html) may give you ideas.

Comment: Or, you could look [at this](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/2011/10/add-value-labels-to-top-of-bars-in-bar.html), [or this](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/datastrings.html)

Comment: What is the status on this question? Have you made progress?